# How to assert on the existence of a certain value in an array

Tags: java, assert

```
class Configuration { String name, String type }
Configuration[] configurations = ..
```

I want to put a assert check to see if the array contains a certain value in the name field (say name="Any"). We are currently looping the array to check this, what would be an elegant way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Streams API:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.stream(configurations).anyMatch(c -> "Any".equals(c.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another slight variation using the [Streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
assertTrue(Arrays
    .stream(configurations)
    .map(c -> c.name)
    .anyMatch("ValueToLookFor"::equals));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/):

```
assertThat(configurations).extracting(Configuration::getName).contains("Any");
```

or you may prefer:

```
assertThat(configurations).anyMatch(c -> "Any".equals(c.name));
```